# How to resolve 'Method Not Allowed' using delete link?

Tags: python, post, flask

I am working on python-flask blog tutorial. I have made a routing to delete a post according to the tutorial. however, when I click the delete link I get a "Method Not Allowed" message. It works when I include the 'GET' method in the routing decorator, but I do not understand why it is needed in this case and in the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0oDDZrDz9U) it seems to be working fine with only 'POST'.

```
@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>/delete', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def post_delete(post_id):

    # Get the post from id.
    post_to_delete = Post.query.filter_by(id=post_id).first_or_404("There is no post with ID = {}".format(post_id))

    # Check if the current user is the author of the post.
    if post_to_delete.author != current_user:

        # Abort the action.
        abort(403)

    # Commit changes to post to database.
    db.session.delete(post_to_delete)
    db.session.commit()

    # Inform user that new post has been deleted.
    flash("Your post has been deleted!")

    # Redirect to the home page.
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: Is that an error 405 you're referring to? If so, making a GET request using POST only is not allowed

Comment: Instead of `POST /post/<int:post_id>/delete` it would be much cleaner to use `DELETE /post/<int:post_id>` ([see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE))

Comment: @Tomalak That makes sense, but I am for now following the tutorial and I would still like to understand why using the 'POST' method is not working for me here.

Comment: Because you are not actually doing POST requests in your client code, just as abdullahalali said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, click a link can only trigger a GET request. If you want to send a POST request, you have to use `<form>` or JavaScript:

```html
<form action="/post/1/delete" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes of course! I just made a link instead of a button. That is why it did not work. Thanks :)